# Printing label and associated pixel value from raster?

Tags: arcgis-pro, classification

I have created a classified raster using the ArcGIS Pro image classification wizard. Unfortunately, I am unable to get the table of pixel intensities & associated labels to export to .csv.

When I export the raster, I get a summarized table of the classes and counts. However, I want to train a custom neural network with these images and want to compare the output from the classification raster (R G B individual values across the image).

Is there a way to do this?

I do not have access to the ESRI Imagery Analyst license so am unable to export the training for deep learning.

Comment: Have you tried RasterToNumpyArray?

Comment: I have, however, the output (CSV) in this case is a whopping 1.7 GB. I utilized R to fread, but still have trouble seeing the export. I do see a ton of zeros in the array though and not seeing any indication of 'class'.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have been able to get somewhere with your suggestion. Using arcpy, I converted it. Seeingas how the array is much too large to open by CSV (or R, for that matter), I was able to extract unique values. I am guessing that these values (0, 1, 2, 3) match the class values (of which, there are four total). While this gives the class value per pixel, I am still unsure of to get the actual RGB values.